# Why explicitly require that a martingale is measurable

Tags: probability, probability-theory, martingales

When defining martingales (for example p. 458 Billingsley) one explicitly requires that $X_n$ is measurable $\mathscr{F}_n$. But doesn't this follow by the requirement $E[X_{n+1} \vert \mathscr{F}_n] = X_n$ ?

Thanks!

Comment: No, it doesn't. Conditional expectation is only a.s. defined, thus you will need the additional assumption that $\mathscr F_n$ is complete to arrive at the $\mathscr F_n$-measurability of $X_n$.

Comment: When $\mathcal F_n$ is the natural filtration of $X_n$, it is necessarily true that $X_n$ is $\mathcal F_n$-measurable. However, this is not always the case; $\mathcal F_n$ may be some other filtration.